# Apollo GraphQL - TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOrCreateUser' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm following this tutorial https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/mutation-resolvers/#book-trips

and have ended up getting this error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOrCreateUser' of undefined",
            "    at login
```

Below is the function I use to call login:

```
mutation LoginUser {
  login(email: "daisy@apollographql.com") {
    token
  }
}
```

The file below is where findOrCreateUser is called:
**src/resolvers.js**

```
module.exports = {
    Mutation: {
        login: async (_, {email}, {dataSources}) => {
            const user = await dataSources.userAPI.findOrCreateUser({ email });
            if (user) {
                user.token = Buffer.from(email).toString('base64');
                return user;
            }
        },
    },
```

This is where dataSources is defined:
**src/index.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server');
const typeDefs = require('./schema');
const { createStore } = require('./utils');
const resolvers = require('./resolvers');
const isEmail = require('isemail');

const LaunchAPI = require('./datasources/launch');
const UserAPI = require('./datasources/user');

const store = createStore();

const server = new ApolloServer({
    context: async ({req}) => {
        const auth = req.headers && req.headers.authorization || '';
        const email = Buffer.from(auth, 'base64').toString('ascii');
        if (!isEmail.validate(email)) return {user: null};
        // find a user by their email
        const users = await store.user.findOrCreate({ where: { email } });
        const user = users && users[0] || null;
        return { user: {...user.dataValues } };
    },
    dataSources: () => ({
        launchAPI: new LaunchAPI(),
        UserAPI: new UserAPI({store})
    }),
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
});

server.listen().then(() => {
    console.log(`
        Server is running!
        Listening on port 4000
        Explore at https://studio.apollographql.com/dev
    `)
});
```

Comment: UserAPI  vs userAPI

Comment: what is the solution!!

Answer (score 0):

As xadm mentioned in the comment the issues is your usage of `userAPI` vs `UserAPI`. the datasource object is created in index.js in the following block

```
dataSources: () => ({
        launchAPI: new LaunchAPI(),
        UserAPI: new UserAPI({store})
    }),
```

here you defined `datasources.UserAPI` however in resolvers.js you refer to it as `datasources.userAPI` (note the difference in capitalization of userAPI). Your problem can be resolved by changing the above code block to

```
dataSources: () => ({
        launchAPI: new LaunchAPI(),
        userAPI: new UserAPI({store})
    }),
```